# Onlyoffice documentserver 4.1.5 alter documents

Tags: onlyoffice

I'm using the new integration of onlyoffice, version 4.1.5 using the docker available.
I'm have several issues when editing documents, it seems it's not working right. I was used to use the version 3 which didn't have such problems.
A common issue I notice is when trying to save a docx file, it loses the format (margins are set to 0), with odt file it corrupts the file making it not readable. I'm trying to investigate more, but as I see there's also something wrong with the mimetype which seems to be changed. For example opening an odt file and save it in onlyoffice it completely breaks it and change the mimetype from OOXML into Zip data (MIME type "K,("?)

Anyone experiencing that?

Comment: You mention `margins are set to 0`. Are you trying to open docx generated by ONLYOFFICE in LibreOffice, am I right?. If yes - docx is not native format for LibreOffice, and I thought it have some troubles with opening it. MS Word opens that docx files with correct margins

Comment: I agree with you about MIME-types, seems there is problem in 4.1 version of `documentserver`, it will be fixed in 4.2 which we bill release in several weeks

Comment: In version 3 we used some stuff from libreoffice, it maybe worked, but we do not support version 3 any more and do not use libreoffice at all.